# In mercurial, how do I get a preview of the number of files with true conflicts?

Tags: mercurial, merge

I'd like a quick way to know how many conflicts I will need to merge manually.  Is this built-in?  Or is there an existing tool to use as the merger to just count this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no built in predictor command, as it would take as much effort computationally as doing the merge. However, if you do a `hg --config ui.merge=internal:fail merge` it will exit immediately and you can do a `hg resolve --list`.

That will show you what you're in for, and you can either continue with `hg resolve --all` or give up with `hg update -C .`

Comment: When you say exit immediately you don't mean Ctrl-C while merge is running do you?

Comment: No, just exit the merge tools that launches w/o saving anything or picking anything.  Alternately you could do the merge like this:

hg --config ui.merge=internal:fail merge

which will dump you right back to the command prompt so you can do your 'hg resolve --list'.

Comment: Using the --config... works great.  Thanks to Ry4an for the answer and clarification and to dimo414 for asking the question needed to get the clarification!

Comment: One point on this, kdiff3 will automatically resolve some of the conflicts that the internal merge tool won't, so you probably don't have as much work to do as you think.